# CORS anywhere prefixed on external api gets 400 Header Required

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks, http-status-code-400, cors-anywhere

I'm using React and want to display an image from an external api and have prefixed the api with a CORS anywhere url. But I get this error message:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/8c05c536-c110-402d-82da-60f25f6b0e1c 400 (Header required)
```

I have been searching for a solution but I only find solutions on how to fix this on server side. But since this is an external api I can't do that. Is there any solution to this?

Here is my code:

```
export const SingleProductImage = (props) => {
  const [articleImg, setArticleImg] = useState('')
  console.log(articleImg)
  console.log(props.fileid)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/${props.fileid}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Access-Token': accessToken,
        'Client-Secret': clientSecret,
      }
    })

      .then((res) => {
        setArticleImg(res.url)
      
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }, [props.fileid])

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={articleImg} alt="product" className="img" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the URL you're trying to proxy is currently not reachable via cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com

more info here: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to fetch a merged url *https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/8c05c536-c110-402d-82da-60f25f6b0e1c* this is basically **https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/** and **https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/8c05c536-c110-402d-82da-60f25f6b0e1c** .

You have to fetch the *https://api.fortnox.se/3/archive/8c05c536-c110-402d-82da-60f25f6b0e1c* API and then proceed with the access token